# GAE Go template.Execute, passing a struct with vector

Tags: parsing, google-app-engine, templates, vector, go

I'm storing some data in a Go app in a struct's vector.Vector for convenience. I want to display all the data from the vector on Google App Engine webpage through template.Execute. Is it possible and how would I access the data in the parsed html file? Would it be easier if I used an array or slice instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slices.

> [Go Weekly Snapshot History 2011-10-18](http://tip.goneat.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-10-18)
>
> The `container/vector` package has been deleted. Slices are better:
>   [SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).